# jQuery File Upload, enable binary file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file-upload, mime-types

I am currently looking for an HTML5 and Javascript based file uploader and came across jQuery File Upload. jQuery File Upload seems to have everything I need.
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html

To quickly test jQuery File Upload capabilities in connection with Django I was lucky to find the "django-jquery-file-upload" project on GitHub. This example perfectly works with image gif, jpeg and png files.

**The Problem:**

I require jQuery File Upload allowing users to upload binary files with a mime type of "application/octet-stream" and with extension "xyz". In addition I want to increase the maximum upload file size to 30MB. At a glance this all seems quite straight forward since jQuery File Upload comes with the "***acceptFileTypes***" and "***maxFileSize***" properties. However those properties somehow are not getting taken into account. For hours I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work. I have also attempted most of the suggestions provided with stackoverflow.com/questions/17451629/maxfilesize-and-acceptfiletypes-in-blueimp-file-upload-plugin-do-not-work-why

How can I get the basic example f("picture_basic_form.html") on github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload to enable it for "application/octet-stream" uploads?

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = '/upload/basic/';
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        crossDomain: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probably is a server side probem, since I don't see anything that can limit the file upload in your code, plus from the JQUEY UI demo: `Only image files (JPG, GIF, PNG) are allowed in this demo (by default there is no file type restriction).`

Comment: Plus js to check mimetype or extension isn't reliable, since they aren't reliable and subject of sproof, plus you have got problemsso I would rely only on php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

@Razorphyn, you are right, the problem was server side. After your comment I went through it again and found it. `models.ImageField` had to be changed to `models.FileField`.

```html
-    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
+    file = models.FileField(upload_to="pictures")
```

The working example can be found at https://github.com/quater/django-jquery-file-upload.